# HTML CSS JS Multiple modal images with responsive width

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, modal-dialog

I have a problem implementing 6 modal images in the same web page. Basically, as far as I can see, the problem is that they are all inheriting CSS from the last one.
What I want to do is to change the width of the modal images according to the width of the device which they will be opened with.
Since it's the first time I use modal images, I don't get if I'm doing a mistake somewhere or if the modal I made can't work in the way I wish.

HTML

```
<img id="smartphone-std" class="thumbnail1" title="Small Mobile Screenshot" src="../path/img0.png" alt="smartphone screenshot"/>
<img id="tablet-std" class="thumbnail2" title="Tablet Screenshot" src="../path/img1.png" alt="tablet screenshot"/>
<img id="desktop-std" class="thumbnail3" title="Deskop Screenshot" src="../path/img2.png" alt="desktop screenshot"/>
<img id="smartphone-plus" class="thumbnail1" title="Small Mobile Screenshot" src="../path/img3.png" alt="smartphone screenshot"/>
<img id="tablet-plus" class="thumbnail2" title="Tablet Screenshot" src="../path/img4.png" alt="tablet screenshot"/>
<img id="desktop-plus" class="thumbnail3" title="Deskop Screenshot" src="../path/img5.png" alt="desktop screenshot"/>

<div id="zoom1" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="caption">To go back, click on the image.</div>
    <img class="modal-content" id="smartphoneZoom-std" />
</div>

<div id="zoom2" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="caption">To go back, click on the image.</div>
    <img class="modal-content" id="tabletZoom-std"/>
</div>

<div id="zoom3" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="caption">To go back, click on the image.</div>
    <img class="modal-content" id="desktopZoom-std"/>
</div>

<div id="zoom4" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="caption">To go back, click on the image.</div>
    <img class="modal-content" id="smartphoneZoom-plus"/>
</div>

<div id="zoom5" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="caption">To go back, click on the image.</div>
    <img class="modal-content" id="tabletZoom-plus"/>
</div>

<div id="zoom6" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div id="caption">To go back, click on the image.</div>
    <img class="modal-content" id="desktopZoom-plus"/>
</div>
```

CSS 400px breakpoint

I used the code found on w3school.com to learn how modal images work and in order to have exactly the same result.

```
/*modal*/

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px 0;
    height:3%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) 400px */
#smartphoneZoom-std ,
#tabletZoom-std,
#desktopZoom-std ,
#smartphoneZoom-plus,
#tabletZoom-plus,
#desktopZoom-plus{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:30%;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #ffa500;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

CSS 740px breakpoint

In this breakpoint the max-width of smartphone modal is set, while the desktop and tablet one is inherited from the previous breakpoints.

```
/* modal */

/* Modal Content (Image) 740px */
#smartphoneZoom-std {
    max-width: 620px;
}

#smartphoneZoom-plus {
    max-width: 620px;
}
```

CSS 955px breakpoint

In this breakpoint the max-width of tablet and desktop modal is set, while the smartphone one is inherited from the previous breakpoints.

```
/* modal */

/* Modal Content (Image) 955px */
#tabletZoom-std {
    max-width: 800px;
}

#desktopZoom-std {
    max-width: 955px;
}

#tabletZoom-plus {
    max-width: 800px;
}

#desktopZoom-plus {
    max-width: 955px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

If possible I'd like to know if there's a way to shrink a bit this script because this function is always doing the same thing just with different images.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    /* -- STD -- */

    //zoom1

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('zoom1');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('smartphone-std');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('smartphoneZoom-std');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    // Close the modal if the image is clicked
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("smartphoneZoom-std");
    bigImg.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    //zoom2

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('zoom2');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('tablet-std');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('tabletZoom-std');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    // Close the modal if the image is clicked
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("tabletZoom-std");
    bigImg.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    //zoom3

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('zoom3');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('desktop-std');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('desktopZoom-std');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    // Close the modal if the image is clicked
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("desktopZoom-std");
    bigImg.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    /* --PLUS-- */

    //zoom4

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('zoom4');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('smartphone-plus');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('smartphoneZoom-plus');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[3];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    // Close the modal if the image is clicked
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("smartphoneZoom-plus");
    bigImg.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    //zoom5

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('zoom5');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('tablet-plus');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('tabletZoom-plus');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[4];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    // Close the modal if the image is clicked
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("tabletZoom-plus");
    bigImg.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    //zoom6

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('zoom6');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('desktop-plus');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('desktopZoom-plus');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[5];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    // Close the modal if the image is clicked
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("desktopZoom-plus");
    bigImg.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }
}
```

I hope I explained the problem well enough. Thank you everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of peculiar things within the code you posted. I'll first explain why the code doesn't seem to fit the intention: *"What I want to do is to change the width of the modal images according to the width of the device which they will be opened with."* Afterwards I'll explain why currently all six thumbnails open in the zoom6 modal which has the id "desktopZoom-plus". Meaning right now, regardless of which thumbnail you click, or on which device you view the image, it shows a zoomed image with a max-width of 995px. As last I will try to provide a solution.

***The code doesn't fit the intention:***

Right now the code tries to show six thumbnails, **each thumbnail showing a different sized zoomed version.** This is regardless of the device they're viewed on. What seems to be inteded is to have 6 thumbnails, **each showing the same sized zoomed versions**. The size should be responsive to the type of device they're being viewed on.

***The Javascript Issue:***

For all of the six images, it declares the onclick function as follows:

```
img.onclick = function(){
```

All the six images are referred to with the same variable 'img'. This means that it changes the actual onclick function of every previous image, everytime it gives the variable 'img' an onclick function. So only the last declared function will be applied too all images. Underneath is an example of the same unintended behaviour. If you click on 'hello' it says 'bye' instead of 'hello', because the function has been changed.

```js
var clickable_div = document.getElementById("hello");
clickable_div.onclick = function()
{
 alert(clickable_div.innerHTML);
}

var clickable_div = document.getElementById("bye");
clickable_div.onclick = function()
{
 alert(clickable_div.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
body div
{
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hello
{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#bye
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello"> hello </div>
<div id="bye"> bye </div>
```

In this case it implies that only the zoom6 modal will be opened. All images have the exact same function:

```
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //stops the sidebar scrolling
}
```

They will display the zoom6 modal. Then update the zoom6 modal image with the src and alt of the clicked thumbnail. As last it will change the overflow to hidden.

*Perhaps interesting to know, but somewhat irrelevant: The function uses the correct src and alt of the clicked thumbnail, because the onclick function retreives the src and alt by refering to the thumbnail as 'this'. If instead it would be declared as 'img.src', it would only show a zoomed version of the last thumbnail, despite on which thumbnail you c*lick.

***Solution***

If I understand you correctly, you want all the six images to basically have the same function, namely opening a modal box and displaying a larger (responsive) version. Below I'll show how to give all images this function within javascript. Alternatively you could give the images an onclick function in html.

You want the max-width of the displayed image in the modal box to be responsive. This is best achieved with pure css, namely with the @media rule. An explanation about how this works can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
I suggest removing all css from #smartphoneZoom-std to #desktopZoom-plus. And replacing it with a single id. Then apply the @media rule to set different max-width for differently sized devices.

Keep in mind that this is just my take on it. It could be that there are more efficient ways or effective ways. Also, it requires some changes of the actual ids/class names given that there should only be 1 modal box.

***Javscript:***

Lets assume you put all images inside a:

```
<div id="thumbnail_wrapper">
```

The following javascript would do then (given that you only use one modal box now with an id of "zoom" an image with the id of "bigImg" and span with the id of "closeBigImg"):

```
var thumbnail_wrapper = document.getElementById("thumbnail_wrapper");
var thumbnails_array = thumbnail_wrapper.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var loop = 0; loop < thumbnails_array.length; loop++)
{
  var thumbnail = thumbnails_array[loop];
  thumbnail.setAttribute("onclick", "open_the_modal(this);");
}

// the variables
var modal = document.getElementById('zoom'); // there should only be 1
var modalImg = document.getElementById('bigImg');
var captionText = document.getElementById('modal_caption');
var bigImg = document.getElementById('bigImg');
var span = document.getElementsById('closeBigImg'); 

function open_the_modal(this)
{
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}

// Close the modal if the image is clicked
bigImg.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

*Note: In your initial code the caption within the modal boxes all have the same id. An id should be unique, so instead it should be a class instead of id, or for there to be only one (like in my solution).*

Comment: Thank you very much Rup7ur3! 
The explaination was really clear, and thank you again for all the advices!